# im trying to call the bid function on my bidding contract from an outside contract but im getting "undeclared identifier" error... please help

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript

Smart contract code:

```
interface IERC721 {
    function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint tokenId
    ) external;

    function transferFrom(
        address,
        address,
        uint
    ) external;
}

    contract EnglishAuction {
        event Start();
        event Bid(address indexed sender, uint amount);
        event withdraw(address indexed bidder, uint amount);
        event end(address winner, uint amount); // why is "indexed in the first two events but not in the third event?
        
        IERC721 public nft;
        uint public nftId;

        address payable public seller;
        uint public endAt;
        bool public started;
        bool public ended;

        address public highestBidder;
        uint public highestBid;
        mapping(address => uint) public bids;

        constructor(address _nft, uint _nftId, uint _startingBid) payable {
            nft = IERC721(_nft);
            nftId = _nftId;
            
            seller = payable(msg.sender);
            highestBid = _startingBid;
        }

        function start() external {
            require(!started, "started");
            require(msg.sender == seller, "seller");

            nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
            started = true;
            endAt = block.timestamp + 7 days;

            emit Start();
        }

        function bid() external payable {
            require(started, "not started");
            require(block.timestamp < endAt, "ended");
            require(msg.value > highestBid, "value < highest");

            highestBidder = msg.sender;
            highestBid = msg.value;
        }

}


contract see {
    
    function bidding() public payable {
        EnglishAuction englishauction = new EnglishAuction(_nft, _nftId, _startingBid);
        englishauction.bid();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bidding()` function, you must declare the parameters to pass to `EnglishAuction` instance. In your case, when you define `bidding()` function you didn't declare the following parameters:

- _nft
- _nftId
- _startingBid
  To solve this issue, you must declare this parameters. I adjusted your smart contract, you can see it in the following lines.

Smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC721 { 
    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokenId) external;
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint) external;
}

contract EnglishAuction {
    event Start();
    event Bid(address indexed sender, uint amount);
    event withdraw(address indexed bidder, uint amount);
    event end(address winner, uint amount); // why is "indexed in the first two events but not in the third event?
    
    IERC721 public nft;
    uint public nftId;

    address payable public seller;
    uint public endAt;
    bool public started;
    bool public ended;

    address public highestBidder;
    uint public highestBid;
    mapping(address => uint) public bids;

    constructor(address _nft, uint _nftId, uint _startingBid) payable {
        nft = IERC721(_nft);
        nftId = _nftId;
        
        seller = payable(msg.sender);
        highestBid = _startingBid;
    }

    function start() external {
        require(!started, "started");
        require(msg.sender == seller, "seller");

        nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId);
        started = true;
        endAt = block.timestamp + 7 days;

        emit Start();
    }

    function bid() external payable {
        require(started, "not started");
        require(block.timestamp < endAt, "ended");
        require(msg.value > highestBid, "value < highest");

        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        highestBid = msg.value;
    }
}

contract see {

    // NOTE: I changed the method signature!
    function bidding(address _nft, uint _nftId, uint _startingBid) public payable {
        EnglishAuction englishauction = new EnglishAuction(_nft, _nftId, _startingBid);
        englishauction.bid();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful.